# asp bbc rss feed cutsoff early

Tags: xml, asp-classic, rss

Am using the following to read BBC rss feed - but seems to randomly cut off the feed early - please advise TQ

```
  Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  objHTTP.open "GET","http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml",false
  objHTTP.send
  RSSFeed = objHTTP.responseText
  set objHTTP = Nothing
  RSSFeed = Replace(RSSFeed, Chr(150), Chr(32))
  RSSFeed = Replace(RSSFeed, ":", "")
  Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
  Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
  response.Write(RSSFeed)
```

I was using [zrssfeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/) but then google removed the feed API and no longer works - so decided to make my own jquery news panel.

```
function getFeed(sender, uri) {
jQuery.getFeed({
    url: 'newsproxy.asp',
    success: function(feed) {
        var html = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 5; i++) {
            var item = feed.items[i];
            html += '<div class="rssFeed">'
            + '<div class="rssHeader">'
            + '<a href="'
            + item.link
            + '">'
            + item.title
            + '</a>'
            + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="rssDate">'
            + item.updated
            + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="rssBody">'
            + item.description
            + '</div></div>';
        }
        jQuery(sender).html(html);
    }    
});
}
```

UPDATE: ditched asp 'proxy' and used this link in jq func - works fine

```
url: 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml',
```

Comment: why are you checking `i < 5` in `for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 5; i++) {`?

Comment: You sure it's random may be it's more like after the first 5 items? ;)

Comment: lol - issue is not with jfunc (just put there for context - only want 5 items) - issue occurs with asp code, seems to just cut off 1/2 way through a news item.
UPDATE: just checked now and is working fine, will check tomorrow morning